# is this lanuage or it' complement not Turing-recognisable

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, turing-recognizable

K = {<J, a, b, c> : J is a Java program, a, b, and c are integer variables declared in J, and throughout the execution of J, a never has the same value as b and a never has the same value as c}.

I'm aware the problem is not actually decidable as I performed a reduction from ATM (or halting problem), which proves it is not decidable, but my question is it Turing-recognizable or not Turing-recognizable? if not is it co-Turing recognizable and what would be the complement? I would assume it would be:

K' = {<J, a, b, c>: J is a Java program, a, b, and c are integer variables declared in J, and throughout the execution of J, a always has the same value as b and a never has the same value as c}.

Comment: Please proof-read your question and [edit] it to correct all typos and errors.  The name is "Turing", not "turing" or "turning".  Please ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of your language $K$ is easily seen to be recognizable: If $J$ isn't a valid Java programme, or it is lacking the specified integer variables, we can easily tell. Otherwise, we run the Java programme and monitor the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$. If we see $a$ to have the same value as $b$, or if we see $a$ to have the same value as $c$, we are also in the complement of $K$. This process will identify all inputs not belonging to $K$, so we have what we want.

Comment: Would K be not TR?